# How to add a new language for mysql's error messages?

Tags: mysql, translation

In $MySqlHome/share folder, there are 25 subfolders (25 languages) and errmsg-utf8.txt file which contains translations of the error messages. Under each subfolder there is a errmsg.sys.

I'd like to add a new language (zh-CN) and translate some of the messages.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source file to edit is `sql/share/errmsg-utf8.txt`

At the top of this file, a line like

```
languages ... french=fre ...
```

declares the list of languages with abbreviations.

During the build, the program `comp_err` generates the language files under `sql/share`

If you add a new language in the header, it should pick it up.

Look also at file `sql/share/cmake_install.cmake`
to install each generated language file.

Note: All the files listed here belong to the MySQL source code, you need to build from source to use the error generator (`comp_err`)

Comment: Thnaks for your tip. Can I run comp_err separately (without rebuilding mysql) to add a new language? I find this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comp-err.html.

Comment: Never tried because I build from source, but I think comp_err can be used alone: there is no need to change it or recompile it even to add a new language. Remember to accept the answer if it helps.