# Translate the language of error messages in MySQL to Hindi

Tags: mysql

I am working on MySQL 5.6, 
I want to translate my error message language to Hindi language.I got open source code of MySQL and it have errormsg.txt file. My question is can I edit and add Hindi translator that file and how can I execute the edited source code.if it is not possible then give me the idea to translate the language of error messages.

Comment: You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, this question is not exactly about programming per say because you don't have a programming error that you're trying to solve. Obviously, if you have the source code you *can* (in principle) start working to make whatever translation you wish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new language for mysql's error messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302958/how-to-add-a-new-language-for-mysqls-error-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Just checked that MariaDB 10.3.8 supports hi_IN as a locale for error messages. Maybe you could consider an upgrade if it's a really important feature for you.

```
SET lc_messages = 'hi_IN';
```

[image]